203045/break-before-make-spdt-relay-out-of-2-spst-relays
I have question concerning: "make before break" relay instead of the posting "break before make" relay. (see post 203045 originally drawn with IC 74HC02 Quadruple 2-Input Positive-NOR)
I built the circuit with a CD4001 and connected 2 monostable relays(5 Volts) to the output pins. The circuit is working (naturally) however the outcome is not what I am looking for.
I am looking for a circuit that can switch a 2-way solenoid/coil (relay) of a model railroad semaphore wing signal.
As you might know, those solenoids/coils do not like a continuous current of 16 VAC.
Specific information of the model rail voltage/current
-Voltage/current: 16-18 V AC
-Switching of semaphore coils: the coils of the wing signal are switched by means of  push-buttons which are connected to "0" (Brown: GND AC) and the common current (Yellow) of
16-18 V AC
The semaphore wing signal is switched over "0" (mass or GND). So push switch 1: wing is raised, push switch 2 wing is lowered. The push-buttons are momentary switches.
I do not want to use the pushbuttons but instead I use an infrared light gate.
The OUTPUT of the IR gate is + 5 V.
As soon as the IR gate is HIGH (=5 V= 1) the wing signal is raised. This will be effected by the 1st monostable relay, which activates the NO pin side but immediately disconnect the N0 pin otherwise the solenoid/coil receives continuous current and that I like to prevent.
After approx. 30 seconds, the wing signal is lowered automatically which will be effected by a RC circuit in connection to the 2nd monostable relay NO pin side and disconnect the NO immediately.

Always respect the author’s intent:
What is the LOGIC GATE circuit for the problem I described? Switch ON, switch OFF.
